# Elastic search search query with Filter

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Am new to elastic search, this is my query to find a exact match in my collection.

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_id": {
                  "query": "1"
               }
            }
         },      
       "filter": {
                "term" : {
                    "team_id":"2",
                    "created_user":"099"
                }
            }     
   }
   }
}
```

By running this query I am getting one record, but my problem is its not matching "team_id" filed. When I change team_id to some other value eg: 4, I am still getting the record with team_id = 2, Please help me to write an elastic search query with three fields. Thanks

Comment: If your `_id` field is unique, your query always returns one query. You are saying that `Give me the result that has _id=1`. Probably, this will return one result, it is not meaningful to filter this result then. It will be better, if you explain what are you trying to do

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Thanks for quick reply, am new to elastic search
my requirement in mysql way is 
select * from message where id = 1 and team_id = 2 and created_user = 099

Comment: If you explain your request in real world(not in elasticsearch way), we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exact match, be sure that fields that you want to make search operation must be [not_analyzed](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping-core-types.html). And it seems you are using multiple case in your filter. You can refactor your query by using [and filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html) like;

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_id": {
                  "query": "1"  // remember that, this will always return one result. Update here according to your needs. For example, use tag instead of _id like tag=responsive in order to get results that matches tag field with responsive
               }
            }
         },      
       "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                  "term": {"team_id":"2"}
                },
                {
                  "term": {"created_user":"099"}
                }
            ]
        }     
   }
}
```